# Clearing Django form fields on form validation error?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a Django form that allows a user to change their password. I find it confusing on form error for the fields to have the *'ed out data still in them.

I've tried several methods for removing form.data, but I keep getting a `This QueryDict instance is immutable` exception message.

Is there a proper way to clear individual form fields or the entire form data set from `clean()`?

Comment: you could use javascript, which would work in 95% of the cases according to: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp; example: http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/clearing-form-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need extra validation using more than one field from a form, override the .clean() method. But if it's just for one field, you can create a clean_field_name() method.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/forms/validation/#ref-forms-validation

Comment: Igor, I know how to validate the form. The issue is when the validation fails, I want to have the form field returned empty, not with the data the user provided.

Comment: Igor is on the right track, though, ChrisW. IMO, you should use the clean() method to validate the two passwords - and if they are not correct clear the self.data fields <at that point>, before raising a validation error.

Comment: Could someone elaborate a little more.  When I try self.data['field'] = None just before raising the validationError nothing happens, and the validation error isn't even raised.

Answer (score 7):

Regarding the immutable QueryDict error, your problem is almost certainly that you have created your form instance like this:

```
form = MyForm(request.POST)
```

This means that form.data *is* the actual QueryDict created from the POST vars. Since the request itself is immutable, you get an error when you try to change anything in it. In this case, saying

```
form.data['field'] = None
```

is exactly the same thing as

```
request.POST['field'] = None
```

To get yourself a form that you can modify, you want to construct it like this:

```
form = MyForm(request.POST.copy())
```

Comment: Note that for a file field or an image field in the form you will have to set form.files and not form.data in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Someone showed me how to do this. This method is working for me:

```
post_vars = {}  
post_vars.update(request.POST)  
form = MyForm(post_vars, auto_id='my-form-%s')  
form.data['fieldname'] = ''  
form.data['fieldname2'] = ''
```

Comment: This works, but it's not very clean since you're doing it at the views level. IMO, you should subclass the default login form and replace the clean() method as Igor suggested. That is, first validate they are correct; clear the relevant self.data fields, and lastly raise a ValidationError.

Comment: any chance you could elaborate?  I still get the immutable querydict errors.

Comment: post_vars.update(request.POST) is a less clean way of doing dict(request.POST). In either case, the values that are submitted by the form that you don't override with form.data end up showing up in the rendered form as u' ' (not sure why this happens though). Using request.POST.copy() as suggested by @Ian worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I just created the form again.

Just try:

```
form = AwesomeForm()
```

and then render it.

Answer (score 0):

Django has a widget that does that:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#passwordinput

now if you are not working with passwords you can do something like this:

```
class NonceInput(Input):
    """
    Hidden Input that resets its value after invalid data is entered
    """
    input_type = 'hidden'
    is_hidden = True

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        return super(NonceInput, self).render(name, None, attrs)
```

Of course you can make any django widget forget its value just by overriding its render method (instead of value I passed None in super call.)

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just delete the password data from the form's cleaned_data during validation?

See [the Django docs for custom validation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) (especially the second block of code).

Answer (score -2):

I guess you need to use JavaScript to hide or remove the text from the container.

Comment: There certainly has to be a way to do this server-side... depending on client-side JavaScript is a pretty messy way to accomplish this.