# How to reset "DELETE" param to False in django's custom formset's clean method

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

I made custom formset with custom clean method in it. It's look like:

```
class MyFormsetBase(forms.models.BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ....
        super(AdvOrderBidFormsetBase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def clean(self):
        ....
        if error:
            raise forms.ValidationError('some validation error')
```

When I deleting some form(with wrong paramaeters) from formset and press submit button(form has DELETE field value == True) I get `error = True` in my clean method so I get ValidationError and return to form window. But the DELETE field value in form doesn't reset. And next time when I will submit my form I will get same ValidationError.
So, could I somehow change value of DELETE field in my custom clean method?

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question is quite old, I recently ran into the same problem. I was able to reset the DELETE field by tweaking with the form.data dictionary. Not a pretty solution, but it works:

```
class MyFormset(BaseModelFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        for form in self.deleted_forms:
            #iterating over only the forms marked for being delete
            if <YOUR_CONDITION>:
                form.data = form.data.copy() # form.data is immutable unless we copy it
                form.data.pop('{prefix}-DELETE'.format(form.prefix)) # Delete the correct 'DELETE' field from the POST data
                form.cleaned_data.pop('DELETE') # Also remove the field from cleaned data as the formset checks this field for deletion
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you return in your clean method?

If the "DELETE field value" attribute (or whatever you mean by this phrase) is still contained in your cleaned data, it will persist.

To remove it, delete it from your cleaned data.

Similar issues are reported here, maybe this helps [Clearing Django form fields on form validation error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353732/clearing-django-form-fields-on-form-validation-error)

Comment: According to [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#custom-formset-validation) formset's cutom clean method doesn't return anything. And DELETE field is an extra [field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#can-delete) that is adds to form if we set can_delete=True. I've tried to pop it from formset's forms but this doesn't help

Comment: Can you give the code where you actually render the formset? If you initialise it from the request, you can surely work on a request.copy() and remove the DELETE=True fields...

Comment: Unfortunately I use mixin view and couldn't add some new logic in it, but I think that I could add some extra parameter to my form, check it in form template and reset field value by JS.

Comment: Resetting via jQuery/JS should be a solution, yes.